# ASP NET Core 5 - accessing (or passing) some value to exception filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, exceptionfilterattribute

In C# .NET Core in a ASP NET 5 Core web app we have a custom exception filter:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
   public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
   {
     ...
```

Which is added to the base controller:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter))]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
```

In the controller using the user login name we read some user properties from an SQL table and set some key properties to the session data - for now the most important is that is he/she is a "web developer" or not. When an exception happens, the exception filter catches that, but the error message is shown must be very different (in detail) if the user has this role or not.

My problem is: how to access the session instance from the exception filter, or better: how to set (pass) this Boolean value to the exception filter?

Thanks your suggestions in advance!

Comment: Consider adding your own custom exceptions with parameters that you really need. I believe this is a better approach than working with a session as suggested below

Comment: I need to know if the current user is a developer or not. Exceptions are thrown in any layer, sometimes .NET Exceptions (null ref exceptions and so on). I don't want to write try-catches, and in several layer this user property is hard to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to sharing information is by accessing the `OnExceptions`'s [`ExceptionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.exceptioncontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) parameter and drilling into your items in the session.

That's `context`.[`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext).[`Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_Items) where `HttpContext` is of type [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and `Items` is an `IDictionary<object, object>`.

Of course, the session parameters need to be saved to session before the exception is thrown. You could do it a different way that may be appealing or not for you: catch the exception and throw a custom one in its place that has a `boolean` property to hold your value. Then you can access that exception's property in the filter via `context`.[`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.exceptioncontext.exception?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ExceptionContext_Exception) after casting to your custom exception type.

Comment: Catching and rethrowing is not an option. We wouldn't want to write a try-catch block into all the controller methods. In that case the general exception filter won't be needed.

Comment: I will check accessing the Session through the HttpContext you had suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Checked, and it works! Thanks!