# AsyncLocal with controller method and a scoped exception filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am struggling to understand why my `AsyncLocal` isn't working as expected. Please see the bits of code below. The controller is decorated with my `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute` to be able to handle any exceptions thrown by methods. The filter is scoped and my `AsyncLocal` is initialized to "123" on start. The "DoWork" method sets the `AsyncLocal` to "666" and throws. I would expect that `OnExceptionAsync` sees "666" but in reality it's "123". Worst of all "DoWork" does not even see "123" but a `null` instead.

I was under the impression the controller method and the exception filter are both running in the same async flow. Either this is not true or I am missing something obvious. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public static readonly AsyncLocal<string> AsyncLocal = new();

    public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute()
    {
        AsyncLocal.Value = "123";
    }

    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var value = AsyncLocal.Value;
        // "value" is "123" here
    }
}

services.AddScoped<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>();


[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiExceptionFilterAttribute))]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ApiExceptionFilterAttribute.AsyncLocal.Value = "666";
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: See point #2 on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816079/9604 I cant confirm this as I'm not an expert here, but I would assume throwing an Exception falls under "Until something happens that would require the context to change". Hopefully someone gives a real answer because I am wondering why also.

Comment: See https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-setting-asynclocalt-values-outside-of-async-methods

Comment: Hi @wpfwannabe, I think you can check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69803325/11398810

Comment: Thanks everyone! I do think that the comment of @davidfowl answers the question. Can you please phrase it as an answer too?